# Css text animation

Tags: css, animation, text, transition

I would like to creat a logo (text) animation like this:

I have this logo (which is a text): {K}
When users open a page (and when cursor is over) transition is from {K} ---> to {Katartika}. Left parenthesis is fixed, and the right one goes to the right side revealing the entire word.
After a few seconds it goes back to {K}.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with CSS transition. I've made this quickly, maybe it's not the best solution but that was my first idea :

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  *zoom: 1;
}
span,
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
h1 {
  width: 1.18em;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 0.4s;
}
h1:hover {
  width: 4.24em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>{Katarina</h1><span>}</span>
</div>
<p>^ HOVER ME! ^</p>
```